# Reading symbol file

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, symbols

I am collecting uncaught exceptions in our iOS app, and am trying to symbolicate the backtraces. Unfortunately what I capture is not in the standard format xcode expects for a crash report, so I am trying to decode the symbols from the symbol file myself. I'm trying to research the format of a symbol file so I can achieve this. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Gwynne Raskind has [enough information](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-04-27-plcrashreporter-and-unwinding-the-stack-with-dwarf.html) to keep you from doing this. You should really use one of the existing solutions.

If you decide to do it anyway, good luck.

Comment: I didn't expect it would be that much of an undertaking. Thanks for that. I'll look into converting our info to the Apple crash report format then.

Comment: Why don't you use an existing crash reporting framework based on PLCrashReporter? That produces standard crash reports, does all the heavy lifting on doing safe crash reporting and there are many out there even doing the symbolication for your. See this for more reasons: http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/objc/Reliable_Crash_Reporting.20110912.html